# Angular Routing By Id

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I have a component called Products. Here are my products listed. When I click on the detail button of the listed product, I want to be directed to the detail page of the relevant product. I am using .NET Core Web API in this part. I was not able to send GET request by id from API part. I will be glad if you help me. Thanks. I have no problems with the API part. It works fine when I check it with Postman.

My products.component.html:

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="card m-3" style="width: 18rem; display: inline-block;">
    <img src="../../../assets/img/1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Starting Price: <span style="color: blueviolet;"><b>{{item.startingPrice}} $</b></span></p>
      <p class="card-text">Ending Date: {{item.endingTime}}</p>
      <a [routerLink]="['/product',item.id]" (click)="detailItem(item)" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

My products.component.ts:

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

items: any;
selectedItem: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  http.get("http://localhost:58426/api/auctions")
    .subscribe(response=> {
     this.items = response;
     console.log(response);
  })
}

  detailItem(item: JSON){
  this.selectedItem = item;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

My product.component.html:

```
<p>product works! {{param.title}}</p>
```

My product.component.ts:

```
  param: any;
  items: any;

 constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(p => {
    this.param = p["id"];
    this.http.get("http://localhost:58426/api/auctions")
      .subscribe(response=> {
      this.items = response;
      console.log(response);
      })
    });
}
```

My API Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Auction Get(int id)
    {
        return _auctionService.GetById(id);
    }
```

Comment: `this.http.get("http://localhost:58426/api/auctions/" + this.param)` ?

Comment: It worked. Thank u. But now console has error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" but working :D